# Why do my program files say (x86) but my processor and operating system is a x64 bit

Tags: java

I'm trying to allocate more ram to my Minecraft server and I'm wondering if I'm having problems with thy java so I look at my PC info and it says I have a 64 bit operating system and a 64 bit processor but when i go to program files it says that I have 32 bit. I've tried downloading java 7 and 8 but it still wont wok should i be trying to download 32 bit java I've always downloaded the 64 bit version of everything.

Comment: The 32-bit JVM runs in the Windows XP emulator in Windows and for maximum compatibility will tell you have an x86.

Comment: dang, this seems like such a long time ago. Thanks for the help I know a hell of a lot more about computers now but it's nice to go back and see how far I've come in a few years.

Comment: In another 4 years you will probably say the same thing. I do and I have been working professionally since 1989.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two catalogues: 'Program Files' and 'Program Files (x86)'. The first one should contain 64-bit applications. The other one contains 32-bit applications. This is normal and doesn't mean you have 32-bit system.

Answer (score 3):

It is entirely possible to have multiple versions installed on your computer. Try checking the version that is most likely being used, the one that is on your path.

```
java -version
```

You should see something like this as a result.

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

If it is 64 bit it will be shown here, 32 bit versions do not explicitly say 32 bit.